# Scale Image Then Add Whitespace to Create Static Size

Tags: wordpress

I'm looking for a solution to wordpress to an issue i'm having. I would like to have a thumbnail with a static image size, scaled with whitespace added to both sides to fit it to the required image size

So lets say my image is 300px x 99px and I want a 100 x 100 thumbnail.The image should scale down to 100 x 33.

like this: http://wpquestions.com/uploads/durin_phpL9cDfa.png